# How to makeTableLayout fit for every screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-tablelayout

I am working  in a game then I had a problem . In my game I had `TableLayout` in this `TableLayout` five `TableRow` and in every `TableRow` five `LinearLayout` finally each `LinearLayout` has one `ImageView`. Now we had twenty five `LinearLayouts` .The game depends on removing The `ImageView's` .

The problem is when I remove the `ImageView's` in the same row or column the size of that row or column is shrink. Why it is Happen?

I think the reason because I put `weight = "1"` for `TableLayout` ,  put `weight = "0.2"` for `TableRow` and put `weight = "0.2"` for `Linearlayout`.

Now, if what I think is correct. How can I make my layout fit for each screens.

The code will explain what I miss.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/table"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:tag="11"
            android:id="@+id/L_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" /> 
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:tag="12"
            android:id="@+id/L_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:tag="13"
            android:id="@+id/L_13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:tag="14"
            android:id="@+id/L_14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:tag="15"
            android:id="@+id/L_15"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="21" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="22" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_23"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="23" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_24"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="24" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_25"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="25" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

  <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_31"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="31" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_32"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:tag="32" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece1"
                android:tag="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="33" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_34"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="34" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_35"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="35" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_41"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="41" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_15"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_42"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="42" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_16"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_43"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="43" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_17"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="44" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_18"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_45"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="45" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_19"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow_5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_51"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="51" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_20"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_52"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="52" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_53"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="53" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_22"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_54"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="54" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_23"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/L_55"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@drawable/area_sand"
            android:tag="55" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/piece_24"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/piece2"
                android:tag="0" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: its not working, its still shrink .

Comment: any soultion l am still stuck here